# Plotly: How to add data labels to stacked bar charts using go.Bar?

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I have a stacked grouped bar chart, and I want to get the data labels for each section of each bar on the graph.

My chart is made as below:

```
stackData = {
    "Leaders Now":[.52, .57, .38, .48],
    "Bottom Now": [.20,  .27, .19, .18],
    # Use differece
    "Leaders Plan": [.17, .06, .12,  .16],
    "Bottom Plan":[.15,.12,.09,.12],
    "labels": [
        "Revenue",
        "Cost",
        "Quality",
        "Flexibility"
    ]
}

fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            marker_color = '#024a70'
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Plan"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            marker_color = '#051c2c'
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            marker_color = '#abe5f0'
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Plan"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            marker_color = '#74d0f0'
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Use Cases",
        yaxis_title="% of Companies"
    )
)
fig3.show()
```

[image]

I just want the % values of each item on the bars, as data labels. This was easy with plotly express but not sure why its not working with something such as

```
fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.0%}',textposition='auto')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. If you found it useful, please consider an upvote as well.

Comment: I'm wondering if its possible to get the bar in a overlay format? Like the 1st bar would be 52%, and the one above it would be overlayed, so it would have value of 69% (instead of 17%). I can post a separate question if necessary. Thanks

Comment: That might be possible. But yes, please post that as a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566529/overlay-instead-of-stack-bars-in-plotly-go here is the post:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just have to specify the `text` attribute for each `go.Bar`, like:

```
go.Bar(
    name="Leaders Now",
    x=stackData["labels"],
    y=stackData["Leaders Now"],
    offsetgroup=0,
    marker_color = '#024a70',
    text = stackData["Leaders Now"]
)
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

stackData = {
    "Leaders Now":[.52, .57, .38, .48],
    "Bottom Now": [.20,  .27, .19, .18],
    # Use differece
    "Leaders Plan": [.17, .06, .12,  .16],
    "Bottom Plan":[.15,.12,.09,.12],
    "labels": [
        "Revenue",
        "Cost",
        "Quality",
        "Flexibility"
    ]
}

# stackData = pd.DataFrame(stackData)

fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            marker_color = '#024a70',
            text = stackData["Leaders Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Plan"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            marker_color = '#051c2c',
            text= stackData["Leaders Plan"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            marker_color = '#abe5f0',
            text = stackData["Bottom Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Plan"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            marker_color = '#74d0f0',
            text = stackData["Bottom Plan"]
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Use Cases",
        yaxis_title="% of Companies"
    )
)

f3 = fig3.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='inside')

fig3.show()
```

Comment: Just want to add for clarity that it is the "base" part of the go.Bar the creates the stacked part of the stacked bar, whereas the offsetgroup controls the horizontal offset (in these dimensions).