# Overlay instead of stack bars in Plotly Go?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a stacked and grouped bar chart, with 2 groups, and I'd like to overlay the columns instead of stack. The output is shown below.
[image]

The code is provided below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

stackData = {
    "Leaders Now":[.52, .57, .38, .48],
    "Bottom Now": [.20,  .27, .19, .18],
    # Use differece
    "Leaders Plan": [.17, .06, .12,  .16],
    "Bottom Plan":[.15,.12,.09,.12],
    "labels": [
        "Revenue",
        "Cost",
        "Quality",
        "Flexibility"
    ]
}

# stackData = pd.DataFrame(stackData)

fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            marker_color = '#024a70',
            text = stackData["Leaders Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Plan"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            marker_color = '#051c2c',
            text= stackData["Leaders Plan"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            marker_color = '#abe5f0',
            text = stackData["Bottom Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Plan"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            marker_color = '#74d0f0',
            text = stackData["Bottom Plan"]
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Use Cases",
        yaxis_title="% of Companies"
    )
)

f3 = fig3.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='inside')

fig3.show()
```

So if possible, the first bar would say  52%, and the one above it would be overlayed, so it would have value of 69% (instead of 17%).

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `text` param to be something like `text=[round(x+y,2) for x,y in zip(stackData["Leaders Plan"], stackData["Leaders Now"])]` which will sum the two values together.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

stackData = {
    "Leaders Now":[.52, .57, .38, .48],
    "Bottom Now": [.20,  .27, .19, .18],
    # Use differece
    "Leaders Plan": [.17, .06, .12,  .16],
    "Bottom Plan":[.15,.12,.09,.12],
    "labels": [
        "Revenue",
        "Cost",
        "Quality",
        "Flexibility"
    ]
}

# stackData = pd.DataFrame(stackData)

fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            marker_color = '#024a70',
            text = stackData["Leaders Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Leaders Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Leaders Plan"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=stackData["Leaders Now"],
            marker_color = '#051c2c',
            text=[round(x+y,2) for x,y in zip(stackData["Leaders Plan"], stackData["Leaders Now"])]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Now",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            marker_color = '#abe5f0',
            text = stackData["Bottom Now"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Bottom Plan",
            x=stackData["labels"],
            y=stackData["Bottom Plan"],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=stackData["Bottom Now"],
            marker_color = '#74d0f0',
            text = [round(x+y,2) for x,y in zip(stackData["Bottom Plan"], stackData["Bottom Now"])]
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Use Cases",
        yaxis_title="% of Companies"
    )
)

f3 = fig3.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig3.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2%}', textposition='inside')

fig3.show()
```

[image]